# QGis Lines around points

Tags: qgis

Im my QGis project there are points representing oil wells and sysmic 2D lines. I'd like to know how many lines are there 1 Km around each well, for example.

Comment: Buffer your points, intersect buffers with your lines, then summarize for count (buffer ID unique, count of unique Seismic ID). I'm not aware of any *really* good summarizing tools for QGIS so you might need to do this in Excel (or equivalent) with a pivot table. The dbf file of a shapefile can be opened with Excel (it's a DBASE IV file). You do mean seismic lines (nothing special) don't you?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

I've created a circle around points with "MMQGIS > Create > Create Buffers", and then I used "MMQGIS > Combine > Spatial Join" to intersect points and area (circle) summaryzing the lines. Worked perfecly!